# Why i could not get accumulator from map instance correctly?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, accumulator

first method
i wonder to use Accumulator to calculate num of "NULL" String in different columns, so i write Spark code as follows(the code is simplified), when i put some input in `appData`'s map operation, i could see std output in spark web ui, the value of accumulator is increased, but when i want to **get the final value in driver**, the accumulators are always be zero, i'll appreciate it if you could do me a favor

```scala
val mapAC = collection.mutable.Map[String, LongAccumulator]()

for (ei <- eventList) { 
  val idNullCN = sc.longAccumulator(ei + "_idNullCN")
  mapAC.put(ei + "_idNullCN", idNullCN)
  val packNullCN = sc.longAccumulator(ei + "_packNullCN")
  mapAC.put(ei + "_packNullCN", packNullCN)
  val positionNullCN = sc.longAccumulator(ei + "_positionNullCN")
  mapAC.put(ei + "_positionNullCN", positionNullCN)
}

val mapBC = sc.broadcast(mapAC)

val res = appData.map(d => {
  val ei = d.eventId
  val map = mapBC.value
  if (d.id.toUpperCase == "NULL") map(ei + "_idNullCN").add(1)
  if (d.pack.toUpperCase == "NULL") map(ei + "_packNullCN").add(1)
  if (d.position.toUpperCase == "NULL") map(ei + "_positionNullCN").add(1)
  ei
})

res.count()

mapBC.value.foreach(ac=>{
  println(ac._1 + ": " + ac._2.value)
})
```

---

second method
i've tried another way to caculate the value by creating a map accumulator like this.

```
import java.util
import java.util.Collections
import org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

class CountMapAccumulator extends AccumulatorV2[String, java.util.Map[String, Long]] {
  private val _map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new util.HashMap[String, Long]())

  override def isZero: Boolean = _map.isEmpty

  override def copy(): CountMapAccumulator = {
    val newAcc = new CountMapAccumulator
    _map.synchronized {
      newAcc._map.putAll(_map)
    }
    newAcc
  }

  override def reset(): Unit = _map.clear()

  override def add(key: String): Unit =  _map.synchronized{_map.put(key, _map.get(key) + 1L)}

  override def merge(other: AccumulatorV2[String, java.util.Map[String, Long]]): Unit = other match {
    case o: CountMapAccumulator => for ((k, v) <- o.value) {
      val oldValue = _map.put(k, v)
      if (oldValue != null) {
        _map.put(k, oldValue.longValue() + v)
      }
    //   println("merge key: "+k+" old val: "+oldValue+" new Value: "+v+" current val: "+_map.get(k))
    }
    case _ => throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
      s"Cannot merge ${this.getClass.getName} with ${other.getClass.getName}")
  }

  override def value: util.Map[String, Long] = _map.synchronized {
    java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap(new util.HashMap[String, Long](_map))
  }

  def setValue(value: Map[String, Long]): Unit = {
    val newValue = mapAsJavaMap(value)
    _map.clear()
    _map.putAll(newValue)
  }
}
```

then i invoke it as follows

```
val tmpMap = collection.mutable.Map[String, Long]()

for (ei <- eventList) {
  tmpMap.put(ei + "_idNullCN", 0L)
  tmpMap.put(ei + "_packNullCN", 0L)
  tmpMap.put(ei + "_positionNullCN", 0L)
}
val accumulator = new CountMapAccumulator
accumulator.setValue(collection.immutable.Map[String,Long](tmpMap.toSeq:_*))
sc.register(accumulator, "CustomAccumulator")

val res = appData.map(d => {
  val ei = d.eventId
  if (d.id.toUpperCase == "NULL") accumulator.add(ei + "_idNullCN")
  if (d.pack.toUpperCase == "NULL") accumulator.add(ei + "_packNullCN")
  if (d.position.toUpperCase == "NULL") accumulator.add(ei + "_positionNullCN")
  if (d.modulePos.toUpperCase == "NULL") accumulator.add(ei + "_modulePosNullCN")
  ei
})

res.count()
accumulator.value.foreach(println)
```

but the accumulator value is still zero either

---

second method correct
since the program ends correctly, i did not check the log, after i take a look, i found this ERROR
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot merge $line105198665522.$read$$iw$$iw$CountMapAccumulator with $line105198665522.$read$$iw$$iw$CountMapAccumulator` so i change merge methd's pattern matching code like this

```
override def merge(other: AccumulatorV2[String, java.util.Map[String, Long]]): Unit = other match {
    case o: AccumulatorV2[String, java.util.Map[String, Long]] => for ((k, v) <- o.value) {
        val oldValue: java.lang.Long = _map.get(k)
        if (oldValue != null) {
        _map.put(k, oldValue.longValue() + v)
        } else {
        _map.put(k, v)
        }
        println(s"key: ${k} oldValue: ${oldValue} newValue: ${v} finalValue: ${_map.get(k)}")
    }
    case _ => throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
      s"Cannot merge ${this.getClass.getName} with ${other.getClass.getName}")
  }
```

after changed o's type, it works finally, but it still confused me what first way behaves.

Comment: You can't get changed values of broadcasted container after execution. Broadcasting using for transfer some helpful data to executors for evaluate some result witch will return. You can just calculate something and return it explicitly from distributed evaluation. Not as side-effect, just result of pure function. Read more about spark and map reduce paradigm.

Comment: I assume you think that `mapAC` is temporary container for some temporary results, in spark it doesn't work so.

Comment: @Boris Azanov i didn't change the map, i just use map to get accumulator by name from map. i think the accumulators should calculate the value correctly, shouldn't they? whatever, when i change to the second way, it seems goes wrong either

Comment: I tried test your first approach locally and it was correct values accumulated.

Comment: @Boris Azanov i think there is lots of difference between local mode and cluster mode.

Answer (score 0):

in your custom accumulator you have mistake in merge function, look at correct:

```
val oldValue: java.lang.Long = _map.get(k)
if (oldValue != null) {
  _map.put(k, oldValue.longValue() + v)
} else {
  _map.put(k, v)
}
```

Comment: i found the error and correct it finally! the ques is updated, thanks for ur help